# My website found the 404 error page but don't show a page content, only write the file name

Tags: html, apache, .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-404

I'm trying to create and normal error 404 redirection page.
Everything works great, but I have a little issue trying to fix.

When I get an error 404 for example its open and specific page in my case I use:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^ERROR 404.php [NC,L]
ErrorDocument 404 error
```

My 404 error page is working well. But shows this when I get and 404 error:

[image]

Shows the file name and not the content inside!

Thank you!
Hope you understand my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution:

Use:

```
ErrorDocument 404 http://localhost/404.php
```

Thank you!